# Does p-adic etale cohomology know the variety has ordinary reduction or not?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

For a smooth proper variety $X$ over discrete valuation ring $\mathcal{O}$ of mixed characteristic $(0,p)$, let $X_K$ be the generic fibre over a generic point $\textbf{Spec} K$ and let $X_k$ be the special fibre over a special point $\textbf{Spec} k$. We say that the variety $X_k$ has ordinary reduction iff the cohomology group $H^i(X_k,d\Omega^j)=0$ for any $i,j$.

My question is that p-adic etale cohomology $H^i_{et}(X,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ of $X_K$ knows $X_k$ has ordinary reduction or not.

Comment: What is the meaning of $d$ in that cohomology group $H^i(X_k, d\Omega^j)$?

Comment: @WillSawin exact differentials of degree $j+1$, often denoted by $B^{j+1}$.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Is $B^{j+1}$ a Zariski sheaf?

Comment: Good point, of course what is meant is the sheaf theoretic image of d, so locally exact differentials.

Answer (score 6):

I think you meant the etale cohomology of the **geometric** generic fiber, equipped with the action of the Galois group of $K$. Moreover, in $p$-adic Hodge theory it is usually necessary to assume that the residue field $k$ is perfect.

In this case, the answer is yes under the additional (customary) assumption that the crystalline and Hodge cohomology groups of $X$ are torsion  free (this assumption is needed for the equivalence of two "standard" definitions of ordinarity: the one you gave and the one in terms of Hodge and Newton polygons). This essentially follows from the results of Bernadette Perrin-Riou "Representations p-adiques ordinaires" in Asterisque no. 223, 1994 "Periodes p-adiques" MR 1293973. See Proposition 6.7 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.02246 (I claim no originality here, but the statement gives what you want).

Comment: @Achinger Thank you very much!! I is exactly the thing I wanted.